# Trello - monitoring all my open cards

Tags: trello, tasks

How can I see all my assigned cards on Trello?

I need to see all the cards assigned to me, independently from the boards. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

This is one of our top feature requests. Here's the card on the development board:

https://trello.com/c/UOIrt48P